# How can a static variable from other file accessed here on the C program below?

Tags: c, linker-errors, external, static-linking

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int function(int);

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    extern b;//can be only declared
    printf("a=%d\n",function(a));
    printf("b=%d\n",value());
    return 0;
}
int function(int v)
{
    return v+1;
}
```

In `file1.c` :

```
static int b=20;

int value() //can't be used on a static function
{
    return b;
}
```

In the code above though I've made variable `b` as `static`, it's accessible from other files. How can it be accessed, as the `static` keyword shouldn't allow the variable to be accessed from other files right? I'm bit confused.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Please remove the redundant tags.

Comment: I don't see that you are accessing `b` directly from `main` or `function`. `value` has direct access to it, and it is returning the value of `b` when called in the `printf`

Comment: @jkb : It shouldn't be printed right ?? That's were I'm confused

Comment: `static` just means the variable can't be accessed *directly, by name* from other source files.  There is nothing wrong with "accessing" it indirectly, by calling a function which does have direct access to it.  It is even possible for such a function to return a pointer to the static variable, and the caller can then use that pointer to access the variable directly (but through the pointer, not via the name `b`).

Comment: It shouldn't be thought of like a security feature, as though the compiler would protect the variable from all possible interference by outside code.  It's mostly just a way to reduce clutter in the global namespace.

Comment: @NateEldredge : Thanks Nate. So only public variables can be accessed from other files ?? Can we access a variable inside a function ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement

```
static int b=20;
```

means the variable `b` will only be visible in its translation unit i.e. in `file1.c`, in which you have defined it.

In the `main()`, which is supposed to be in a different file, you have only declared `b` but not used it. Try to use it and you will find that linker will fail because it will not find the definition of `b`.

```
int main()
{
    int a=1;
    extern int b;    // note the type int in declaration. You have missed it.
    printf("access b = %d\n", b);   // <==== this won't work
    return 0;
}
```

Try to compile your program with above changes and you will see that the linker will throw error.

With above mentioned changes in `main()`, just remove the `static` keyword from variable `b` definition in `file1.c` file and above program will link successfully because then `b` will be a global variable which has external linkage.

From the `value()` you are returning the **value** that variable `b` hold which has nothing to do with whether `b` is *static* or *non-static*.

The lifetime of a static variable is the entire run of the program. You can access the static variable outside of it's scope/translation unit if you have the address of that static variable. Check this:

File `file1.c` :

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int b = 20;

int * retaddr_b (void) {
    return &b;
}

void print_b (void) {
    printf ("b = %d\n", b);
}
```

File `main.c`:

```
int * retaddr_b (void);
void print_b (void);

int main(void)
{
    print_b();                 // print static variable b value 
    int * ptr_b = retaddr_b(); // ptr_b pointing to b
    *ptr_b = 99;               // dereference ptr_b and assign different value
    print_b();                 // print static variable b value
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
b = 20
b = 99
```

Comment: Thanks H.S. So only public variables can be accessed from other files ?? Can we access a variable inside a function ??

Comment: @Meganathan There is no any concept of public variables in `C`. Looks like you are confused between `C` and `C++`. Remember one thing, `C` and `C++` are two different languages. Get in-depth knowledge of storage classes in `C`, familiar yourself with scope, lifetime and external/internal linkage of a variable in `C` and also go through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files).

Answer (score 1):

Its not really accessed there, dint you see below warning when compiled:

`warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘b’ [-Wimplicit-int]`

All you are doing is printing the return value from function `value`.

if you really wanted to see whether it is accessed or not check as below:

comment your `printf("b = %d\n",value());` and use `printf("b = %d\n",b);`
in its place then compile and check.

Comment: Thanks IrAM. So only public variables can be accessed from other files ?? Can we access a variable inside a function ??

Comment: @Meganathan,Its not  clear what you are asking, there is no concept of _public variables_ in `C`(At least that i know of), its better open a new question with some example if you still have some doubts